# Installing Tensorflow and Keras on Intel Pentium

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, pip

For a university we are supposed to implement a TensorFlow project using the python libraries for tensorflow and keras. I can install both of them just fine using pip3, but executing any piece of code results in some kind of error.

I've settled on testing the very complicated code:

```
import keras
```

Using python 3.6 and the newest tensorflow and keras (`pip3 install tensorflow keras`) I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'; 'tensorflow' is not a package`. I checked, and `import tensorflow` finds the package, but returns some error about AVX instructions and dumps the core.

I researched, and my CPU does not support AVX instructions which are part of `tensorflow >= 1.6.0`. I could not find a precompiled version that runs on my laptop without AVX, and I don't have the time to compile myself.

I tried downgrading to `tensorflow == 1.5.0` and `keras == 2.1.3` which was the version when `tensorflow == 1.5.0` was around, but I still get missing errors, for each version and import statement a different one.

For example when I use the code:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

I instead get the error `AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'Sequence'`. I'm on an Intel Pentium, which I assume is the problem. I am fully aware that my setup is in no way suitable for machine learning, and it isn't supposed to be, but nevertheless I'd like to work on that assignment.

Anyone got experience with installing TensorFlow on older machines?

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Intel(R) Pentium(R) 3556U @ 1.70GHz (Dual Core)
- 4GB RAM

Comment: You can download TensorFlow via Anaconda or use the TF wheels from [here](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.13.1/py37/CPU/sse2).

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention, I'm on Linux, just updated the question

Comment: How about using Theano for backend?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski That might be an option, it imports without any errors. But Keras still throws `AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'Sequence'`.

Comment: Try `pip install keras --upgrade`

Comment: First choose a python version compatible with the old versions of tensorflow and keras. Then setup Anaconda with that version (conda create --name greatsnakes python=2.x)

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I read that on every forum, but it doesn't seem to be the problem. For me it seems to be some miscommunication between tensor flow and keras, but the error messages are not particularly helpful

Comment: @Prabindh OK, where do I find which python version I should use?

Comment: That's why I am recommending to use `theano` backend. `tensorflow` is not in anyway hardcoded into `keras`.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Okay, got theano to work. Thank you! Not a real solution, but for this exercise it shouldn' matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same trouble, but it seems to have solved it. (However, the Python version shall be 3.5. )

For CPUs that do not support AVX, the tensorflow must be version 1.5 or lower.
If you want to install Tensorflow 1.5, the Python version must be 3.5 or lower.

**The successful procedure is as follows.**

- (1) Uninstall your Anaconda.
- (2) Download the following version of Anaconda from the following
  URL. 
  Version: Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe
  URL:https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ or https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe
- (3) Double-click the anaconda icon of “(2)” above, and install the
  anaconda according to the GUI instructions.
- (4) Start Anaconda Prompt
- (5) Enter “pip install tensorflow==1.5” in Anaconda Prompt and press
  the return key. Wait for the installation to finish. ([See the log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0iwrUiTKqS2hYsm1BUgt-C1DJcR1b5q/view))
- (6) Enter "pip install keras==2.2.4" in Anaconda Prompt and press the
  return key. Wait for the installation to finish.([See the log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0iwrUiTKqS2hYsm1BUgt-C1DJcR1b5q/view))

This completes the installation. If you Enter " import tensorflow " on Jupiter notebook, some future error may displayed.(See this [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/183I9v3xks7bH6JwOcQ3gohrngkgo354p/view).)

**System:**

My PC does not support AVX like your PC. My PC's specs are as follows.

- PC:Surface Go
- CPU:Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 4415Y　＠　1.60 GHz
- Windows10:64bit

**How to test ?**

Enter and execute the following command on Jupiter Note. Or use this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wkKxhOZKInUUUDGfdQhgpp7CKwAL2AR_/view).

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.keras.__version__)
```

or

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
 sess = tf.Session()
 print(sess.run(hello))
```

If your install is successful, then following message will be displayed on your Jupiter notebook

> 1.5.0
>   2.1.2-tf

**P.S.**

I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions.

Comment: ＠Aram Becker　Did your problem be solved?  
Should the Python version be 3.6?

Comment: I ended up using Theano. I testes your answer in windows and it seems to work. I still haven't found a solution for Linux, although I didn't look through all the no AVX builds

Comment: ＠Aram Becker I'm glad that it seems to be worked. Oops, your OS was Linux. Sorry, but I have never used Linux. But,… how about using one of the following files in the same procedure as above (after step (2).

★If you are using a 64-bit version, use the following file, and
<https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh>
★If you are using a 32-bit version, use the following file
<https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86.sh>

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to the Pentium configuration is not recommended for default tensorflow builds because of AVX dependencies. Also many recent advances in this area are not available in earlier builds of TF and you will find it difficult to replicate research works. Options below:

1. Get a Google Colab (https://colab.research.google.com/) notebook, install Keras and TF and get going with your work
2. There have been genuine requests for this support, refer to this link [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18689] where unofficial builds are provided. See if one of them works
3. Build Tensorflow from scratch (very hard option), with the right set of flags for Bazel (remove all AVX/threading options)

Comment: Well yes, I am aware that Pentium just isn't suitable for Machine learning. But as this is for an university assignment, I won't need to model any papers or use cutting edge features. I have a PC for that at home. What I would like to do is work on a very simple assignment using tensorflow on the move, with unreliable internet connection. I guess my only option will be to go through the no-avx builds one by one and see if I can get one to work.